# Grails + ZK + Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, zk

I have been working on a [Grails](http://grails.org/) based web application. For the UI, I chose the [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) framework via the [ZKGrails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/zkui).

Now while some part of the application is done, I decided to work on the user management and security related stuff. For this I installed the [spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core), which I usually do. Now this is where the I have been stuck. How to use the spring security service in the composers and how to call the methods from the gsps?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all you have to download following .jar

spring-security-acl-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar

more information here 

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Making_Spring_Security_Work_with_ZK
```